# Strange Output from cask command

Tags: homebrew-cask

Today I installed cask via homebrew on my M1 Mac Mini, and wanted to check the version of cask that I had installed. I was not fully sure of the command to complete this, so I tried

cask --version

This gave me a long readout where there were several processes of compiling things in my directory. This may be a dumb question but did I do something that I was not intending to?

Answer (score 0):

`cask --version`, as part of [`Homebrew/brew`](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew), [was deprecated in Oct. 2018](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/commit/ac2cd67861d14110eeb2e492f1e06b95fd7801ee)

Now, only `brew --version` should be enough.